# Failed to parse SourceMap: .../assets/5817df3/css/bootstrap.min.css.map

Tags: yii2

i using BootstrapAsset in my project, code run on local is ok. So i check on server has error about SourceMap.

About error:

Failed to parse SourceMap: My Web url/assets/5817df3/css/bootstrap.min.css.map

I try open this url and see error:

[image]

I don't know exact problem. So how can i fix it, or show me how to debug.

Comment: I update asset manager so it work.

Comment: `'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                    'css' => ['https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'],
                ],`

Comment: I think there is a eay around rather than inserting external link. Framework has it's own bootstrap.

Comment: Yes, i think my server has problem about read .map file. So i using cdn so it' ok, i think CDN so fast.

Comment: It's possible that there is a problem with your server because for it's working fine. I have one off-topic question: do you have Skype or other IM program? I have a few questions but this is not quite a place to ask for.

Comment: @ Edvin Tenovimas The best way is using CDN, i using so fast and simple config. My skype is dungpx.dt. thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution is use CDN  and config by [Customizing Asset Bundles](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html#customizing-asset-bundles)

Answer (score -1):

Please check if you have the same version of bootstrap css and Bootstrap JS.... this happened to me because i had different versions.